# Trying to run two functions on a form they both work independantly but cant get the both to work

Tags: javascript

in essence, I'm trying to validate a single field on a form to make sure it has content (Will eventually want to set a field length too) if the field validates then the second function should run. I've tried putting both functions in the action with && but that doesn't work - I've tried adding the field validation to an click on the button that works - but then doesn't run the next part

Any ideas?

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
  function OnSubmitForm()
  {
    if(document.ScriptFill.status[0].checked == true)
    {
      document.ScriptFill.action ="scriptcheck-complete.php?PUI=<?php echo  $_GET["PUI"] ; ?>&STATUS=unfilled";
    }
    else
    if(document.ScriptFill.status[1].checked == true)
    {
      document.ScriptFill.action ="scriptcheck-complete.php?PUI=<?php echo  $_GET["PUI"] ; ?>&STATUS=filled";
    }
  else
    if(document.ScriptFill.status[2].checked == true)
    {
      document.ScriptFill.action ="scriptcheck-complete.php?PUI=<?php echo  $_GET["PUI"] ; ?>&STATUS=void";
    }
    return true;
  }
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  function validateForm() {
    var x = document.forms["ScriptFill"]["Pharmacy"].value;
    if (x == "") {
      alert("You must enter your GPhC / RCVS number");
      //return false;
    }
  }
</script>
```

Comment: call the second function inside first one

Comment: May I know which the first function you're calling? I'm considering that you want your validateForm function to get exectued first. One way is to call the validateForm function and if the form is validated then you can just call the OnSubmitForm function. You might need to change the type of the button from type='submit' to type='button'. This should do the trick if I got your question correctly.

Comment: So the order would be that when the button is pressed the form checks if the [Pharmacy] field has content if it doesn't an alert warns that content is required and stops - awaiting the user to fill the field. If the field does have content then the form runs the 'OnSubmitForm' function and moves to the next page. I've got both functions working independently - just cannot get them to work together

Answer (score 0):

Whate you can do is something like this in your javascript part:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function OnSubmitForm()
    {
        /** Do what you want **/
        document.getElementById('form').submit();
    }
    
    /** Considering this to be the first function you want to call **/
    function validateForm() {
     // Perform all the validations here
     
     if(your validations pass){
        /* Call your second function */
        OnSubmitForm();
     }
     else{
        return false;
     }
    }
</script>
```

Your HTML:

```
<form action='<your_action>' id='form'>
     <input type='button' onclick='validateForm()' value='Submit'/>
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks for this - I've tried copying and pasting my functions into your example and this does not work - are you able to show me how you would combine my two separate functions into your one combine - youve probably spotted that in a beginner!

Comment: There still exists 2 functions. The very first one that is to be called is the function named "validateForm", you can write your logic in there and then you can call the OnSubmitForm() function, which in turns can dynamically submit the form by the line of code "document.getElementById('form').submit();".